# Control of UIView animations for swift

Tags: swift, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am testing a few things with the UIView animations function and I am slightly confused about the lack of control you have over an animation. Maybe I am missing something

```swift
          UIView.animate(
            withDuration: TimeInterval(Int.random(in: 20 ..< 25)),
            delay: TimeInterval(cloudConfig.delay),
            options: [
                UIView.AnimationOptions.curveLinear,
                UIView.AnimationOptions.repeat,
            ],
            animations: {
                self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: width, y: 0)
                self.parent!.layoutIfNeeded() // important for the animation
            },
            completion: { _ in
                print("hurray I know when it ends, if it would fire on repeat as well :) it does not")
            }
        )
```

This animations simply moves a view from left to right and repeats that process. I cant seem to find anything within the api which allows me to seek to a specific time of the animation and start from there. Or simple things like pause and play, or get the current play position. Is there any way to get some control over the animation, its almost like css animations - zero control.

Thanks for any tips

Comment: I think https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator  is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The UIView class function `UIView.animate(withDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:)` that you are using does not give you any of the things you ask about (the ability to seek to a specific time in the animation, pause/resume, ir get current animation position.)

That said, the different `UIView.animate()` functions work by creating `CABasicAnimation` animations and running them against the view's layers. It is possible to create an animation with one of the `UIView.animate()` functions, and then reach into the resulting layer animations and do what you describe. It's not well documented, confusing, and fussy, but it is possible. I wrote a blog post back in 2015 that shows how to do those things (in Objective-C) http://wareto.com/keyframe-view-animations

The code for that post can be found at https://github.com/DuncanMC/KeyframeViewAnimations

You can pause, resume, or scrub a layer animation back and forth by manipulating the layer's speed, beginTime, and timeoffset properties.

I haven't looked at that code in several years, and haven't attempted to rewrite it in Swift, but it does serve as a roadmap if you want to figure out how to do it. (Beware, it's complicated and fussy.)

As mentioned by TeeJaay, there is a newer animation class, `UIViewPropertyAnimator`, that does support things like pausing and resuming animations, scrubbing them to specific points, etc. If you need those abilities, I suggest you look at that. You should be able to find tutorials on it on the web.